# display taxonomy terms with link

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

How can I print the taxonomy terms with links?? This code work but print the terms without link.. some advice??

```php
function show_all_terms($taxonomy){
    $taxonomy_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
    foreach($taxonomy_terms as $term){
        $terms[] = $term->name;
    }
    if(!empty($terms)) {
        echo join(", ", $terms);
    }
    else{
        echo "No ".$taxonomy."associated with this ".get_post_type();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [get_term_link()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/382094/display-taxonomy-terms-with-link), e.g. change your $terms array to be HTML for the terms or links instead:

```php
    foreach( $taxonomy_terms as $term ) {
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term->slug, $taxonomy );
        if (! is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
            $terms[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name )
                       . '</a>';
        } else {
            // Could not fetch link for this term
            $terms[] = esc_html( $term->name );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function According Your needed for list All Taxonomy Term with Link

```
  function get_term_list($taxonomy){
    
       $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
     
       echo '<ul class="list-cat">';
     
          foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
     
           // The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.
           $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
        
            // If there was an error, continue to the next term.
           if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
               continue;
           }
     
           // We successfully got a link. Print it out.
           echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    } 
   echo '</ul>';

   }
```

And Include & Use This ShortCode For Your page in Admin Panel

> [all_get_term_list taxonomy="category" ]

And This Shortcode Use By Default Taxonomy is category

```
add_shortcode ( 'all_get_term_list', 'all_get_term_list' );

function all_get_term_list($atts){

$a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category'
        ), $atts );

$terms = get_terms($a['taxonomy']);
 
$output.= '<ul class="list-cat">';
 
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
 
    // The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
    
    // If there was an error, continue to the next term.
    if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
        continue;
    }
 
    // We successfully got a link. Print it out.
    $output.= '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
 
$output.= '</ul>';

return $output;

}
```

Comment: yes! work with the first function! thk!